# T-cells Question

Tags: human-biology, homework

T-cells are important for efficient vaccination since they have:

- A. T-cell receptor (TCR)
- B. CD4+
- C. CD8+
- D. Memory

My gut is telling me it's A since the TCR would recognize the antigens but I want to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some reasoning as to why the other options are not correct? A is wrong, by the way. Think about vaccination, and what its goal is. When do we get vaccinated, and why? What is it trying to do?

Comment: @MattDMo Thank you for the response. So after thinking about what a vaccination does, I realized that since it recognizes and remembers invading antigens and tries to prevent them from causing harm that D would make the most sense. As for eliminating CD4+ and CD8+, they seem more of a short-term choice whereas memory would be more long-term for efficiency. Sry for my ignorance, I'm an electrical engineer taking my first bio course in a while

Comment: no worries, I just wanted to get you to think a little more deeply, and it looks like you did. Great job!

Comment: You should choose D, vaccination is about memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vaccination is injecting the low or non-toxic substances that having a pathogen's identifying characteristics into human or animal body. When the animals exposed to the non-injurious pathogens, the immune system will produce a protective material, such as immune hormones, physiologically active substances and specific antibodies. When the animal re-exposure to this pathogen, the animal's immune system will follow its memory and create more protective material to prevent damage from the pathogen.
So choose D

Answer (score 0):

I think T cell when presented to antigen (here vaccine) will produce memory T cell, which on next encounter with the same organism may act much faster and efficiently .so i think the correct answer is option D